# $ E(U_x) $ when $ U_x $ is the number of smaller values in $ X , Y $

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value

[image]>

I have  added my solution here

$ U_x $ be the number of $ y's  $ those are smaller than $ x's $ in independent random samples $  X_1, X_2 ,\ldots, X_n $ and $ Y_1, Y_2,\ldots,Y_m ;$ find $ E(U_x)$ .

At first, I thought of calculating $ E( \min (X , Y )) $
which can be calculated using the cumulative probability function of $X$ and $Y$, but the question says 'number' and also there is no distribution given, which made me doubt my approach.

Anyone who understands, please assist .

Comment: At a first glance, it resembles sort of a variant of [Ballot Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem).

Comment: @user1865345 thanks , I will look into the theory and update the question .

Comment: First try to express $U_x$ in terms of indicator functions.  It is closely related to the Mann-Whitney statistic.

Comment: @Zhanxiong, that is a good assessment considering the construction of Mann-Whitney U statistic but question remains as to how to compute $\mathbf P[Y< X].$

Comment: What's missing here is a clear statement of whether the two samples are meant to be drawn from the same population or different populations (and therefore not necessarily with the same characteristics). I am guessing the intent is that they be samples from the same population, but that should be explicit.

Comment: @glen_b This is the complete question here , which is the major concern because nothing is told about the parent population

Comment: You don't need a specific distribution, since the required probabilities are invariant to monotonic transformation. With the assumption that Xs snd Ys share a distribution the question should be straightforward

Comment: Because the question is ungrammatical and ambiguous (is $U_x$ counting the $y$'s that are smaller than *all* the $x_i$ or *some* of the $x_i$ or perhaps something else?), it might be difficult for anyone to answer.  Could you provide a simple example of how $U_x$ is calculated?

Comment: @whuber I have made some edits to my question , kindly review